# Will Laravel 5.4 run on PHP 5.6.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, xampp

I know that laravel 5.4 need to meets PHP >= 5.6.4. I try to find XAMPP with php 5.6.4 but i have nothing. I just have xampp with php 5.6.3 installed. Will laravel 5.4 run on php 5.6.3?

Comment: is there any reason why you want an old php version? Just install xampp with php 7 or php7.1 https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: i have issue with windows... vc14 is not installed properly. i cant run windows update XD

Comment: fix that first or run homestead, that way you can avoid os -related problems.

Answer (score 2):

Server requirements for laravel 5.4:

PHP >= 5.6.4

OpenSSL PHP Extension

PDO PHP Extension

Mbstring PHP Extension

Tokenizer PHP Extension

XML PHP Extension

[Laravel Installation Server Requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#server-requirements)